# Pass value to label variable in Zebra using Windows Mobile

Tags: compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, zebra-printers, zpl

If I have a variable text and QR Code on my pre-made label in my Zebra printer. How could I pass values to the 2 variables using Windows Mobile 6?

Answer (score 1):

are you suing ZPL2 printer language or what is your label code?

Here is an example using a variable field.

[image]

The lower code window shows what to send to replace the variable data. That is what you have to send viw the communication channel to the printer after you first sended the code of the label in the upper code window.

If you need a more specific help you have to post your label commands etc you already used.

~josef

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. May I know if youre using any software to give me that example? I need a ZPL to Label Previewer.

Ive actually taken a different path... please see my other question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339475/which-should-not-be-included-in-this-zpl-code

Comment: Can you give an example of the label form you have designed in ZPL? Is the label send to the printer at the start of a job or is it loaded into the memory of the printer before?

Comment: Hi, I have a mobile Zebra printer (rw420) at my desk and did a short test with the windows mobile C# sample provided with the Zebra Windows Mobile SDK. I can print and query the printer. Please see Zebra SDK for Windows Mobile. ~Josef

Comment: my problem is though that I dont have any printer with me.

Comment: I understand. But can you layout a label and describe the workflow to print the label? Or is it a bill or ticket to design?